# Locus of points, analytic geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

From point B(0,b) and B'(0,-b) two lines perpendicular to Y-axis are drawn, as BN and B'N' respectively - towards the right. The multiplication of the lengths of those lines is $4a^2$.
Find the set of points where B'N and BN' meet.

Although I think I have the data, in this exercise I can't find in which original formula to plug it into. Either I did something wrong, or it's not the distance formula. Would appreciate help.

Answer is $b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$

[Illustration as I understand it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwfPf.jpg)

[My last attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGCI.jpg)

Comment: It is really hard to make sense of what you have written in your attempt. Can you add the gist of it in your question in [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the error in your solution is where you assume the $x$ co-ordinate of both $N,N'$ as $t$. Why should they have equal $x$ co-ordinates?

[image: Figure]

Let the co-ordinates of $N,N'$ be $(x_1,b),(x_2,-b)$ respectively. The length of the segments $BN, B'N'$ is $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. Thus,$$x_1x_2=4a^2$$

The equation of the line $BN'$ is$$\displaystyle\frac{y-b}{x}=\frac{-2b}{x_2}$$ and the equation of line $B'N$ is$$\displaystyle\frac{y+b}{x}=\frac{2b}{x_1}$$

Their point of intersection is given by $\displaystyle\Big(\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2},b\Big[\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1+x_2}\Big]\Big)=(p,q)$.

Now, notice that $$\displaystyle p=\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2}=\frac{4a^2}{x_1+x_2}\\\displaystyle\Big(\frac qb\Big)^2=\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2}{(x_1+x_2)^2}=\frac{(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2}{(x_1+x_2)^2}=1-16a^2\cdot\Big(\frac p{4a^2}\Big)^2=1-\frac{p^2}{a^2}$$

This gives the required locus as $\displaystyle\frac{p^2}{a^2}+\frac{q^2}{b^2}=1$ or $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution. Could you please explain why you decided to express (q/b)^2? I'm not familiar with that formula.

Comment: $\displaystyle\Big(\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2},b\Big[\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1+x_2}\Big]\Big)=(p,q)\implies q=b\Big[\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1+x_2}\Big]\implies\frac qb=\Big[\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1+x_2}\Big]$. To find the locus of point $(p,q)$, we need to find a relation between $p,q$ by eliminating $x_1,x_2$ using the known relations.